# Handle scrolling with UIView on top of UIScrollView, ScrollView wont Scroll

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, uiscrollview, touch

i want to detect touches in a UIScrollView that has an UIView on top. This UIView has buttons on it, so i cant disable `userInteractionEnabled` on the UIView.

Here is the hierarchy for better understanding:

```
UIView (MainView: (0,0) 320x460)
. .UIScrollView (ScrollView: (0,0) 320x460)
. .UIView (OverlayView: (0,0) 320x250)
. . . .UIButton (button1: 50x50)
. . . .UIButton (button2: 50x50)
. . . .UIButton (button3: 50x50)
```

I can scroll when touched out of the OverlayView. But not on empty places of the OverlayView.

Any advice?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the overlay view as a subview of the scrollview and then updating the overlay view's frame as the scrollview scrolls.

Save the original overlay frame in a member variable on initialize

```
CGRect baseOverlayRect = overlayView.frame;
```

Scroll view delegate method.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    CGPoint overlayOrigin = CGPointMake(baseOverlayRect.origin.x, baseOverlayRect.origin.y + scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    CGRect newOverlayFrame = CGRectMake(overlayOrigin.x, overlayOrigin.y, baseOverlayRect.width, baseOverlayRect.height);
    overlayView.frame = newOverlayFrame;

}
```

Comment: thank you! but i cant change the hierarchy.. I need the View and ScrollView to be independant, at same level, both subviews of MainView.